# python : get list all *.txt files in a directory

Tags: python

i'm beginner in python language

how to get list all `.txt` file in a directory in python language ?

for example get list file :

```
['1.txt','2.txt','3.txt','4.txt','5.txt','6.txt']
```

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Comment: `glob.glob('/path/to/dir/*.txt')` gives you a list of the required filepaths

Comment: Read through the documentation and find a package/module that has that functionality then write some code to use it.

Answer (score 10):

you can use `os`, `subprocess` and `glob` library

`os` library example:

```
import os
os.system("ls *.txt")
```

this command returned all `.txt` file

`subprocess` library example:

```
my_result_command = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=log, stderr=log, shell=True)
```

you can check my_result_command  and get all file or `.txt` file

`glob` library example:

```
import glob
glob.glob('*.txt')
```

Comment: `glob` module is the only reasonable answer in the bunch. Don't encourage slow, brittle, and non-portable solutions like calling out to `ls`, particularly with shell wrapping.